# Redis cluster instance takes long time to load RDB

Tags: redis

I have a Redis dump.rdb file of 177MB in size. It is a snapshot dump of one of the instances of a testing Redis cluster. When I restart the instance, it takes about 25 seconds to load the file into memory. But when I starts a standalone Redis server with the same dump, it only takes about 3.7 seconds to load.

The questions are:

1. Does any one know what causes the difference?
2. Is there a way to shorten the db loading time for the Redis cluster instance?

Comment: it could be rebalancing of the data loaded on the cluster, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hello, Redis Cluster developer here, please could you send me the 177MB file? I will investigate it immediately. Thanks.

Comment: Or even better, are you able to perform certain operations in your environment directly in order to check what's the cause?

Comment: @antirez . Yes, I have access to the environment. What are the operations? How to send you the file? Thanks.

Comment: Cool! You may send the file at the email antirez AT gmail COM. But I also need the `nodes.conf` file of the node.

Comment: Moreover, if you can reproduce the issue, it's even better. Just run the redis-server instance via `gdb` as explained in: https://redis.io/topics/debugging. Then after like 15 seconds the instance is loading data, stop it pressing Ctrl-C and use the gdb `bt` command to get a stack trace. Then update this page with the stack trace. Thanks.